# How to raise a BigInteger to the power of something without pow()

Tags: java, biginteger

My Java Professor wants me to write a program where the user gives a value for x and a value for y, and then computes the value of x^y (x to the power of y), and prints it to the console. I'm not allowed to use the pow() method for this. x and y are int values.

My code, after the user gives x and y values:

```
BigInteger solution = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    for (int i=0; i<y; i++) {
        solution = solution.add(BigInteger.valueOf((x+solution.intValue())*x));
    }
```

But it never works properly. The answer it gives is usually waaaay off. If anyone has code that would correct this problem, your assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're using `add`. I would suggest using `mul`. Start the solution at `x` and then run loop `(y-1)` times.

Comment: You have a math problem, not a programming problem

Comment: Hint: x = 2, y =3;   2^3 = 2 * 2 * 2.  Now solve  2 * 2 * 2 using a loop and then make it generic for any number and power

Comment: . i*0 will always be 0, so your answer will never be right, since it will always be off by one power

Comment: It's very strange to mix `BigInteger` and `int` arithmetic in this way. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: If x and y are int values why convert them to BigInteger?

Comment: @brso05 Because `int`s overflow. What is odd is that the OP converts back to `int` in the middle of the calculation.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I was just wondering if it is a requirement because according to his question it doesn't say it's a requirement he is using BigInteger but that doesn't mean his professor requires it.  The `int` overflow will be very large and depending on what his professor wants `BigInteger` may not be required...

Comment: @brso05 Yes, BigInteger is required, which is a pain to me, because I'm only just learning about it this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to multiply x by itself y times.

```
BigInteger solution;

if (y == 0) {
    solution = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
}
else if (y > 0) {        
    solution = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    for (int i=0; i<y-1; i++) {
        solution = solution.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x));
    }
}
else {
    // Negative powers left as exercise to the reader
}
```

Comment: This actually fails for y = 0

Comment: Addressed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public void function(int x, int y){

    BigInteger sol = BigInteger.ONE;

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

                sol = sol.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(y));

            }

            System.out.println(sol);

    }
```